# Matlab Adding two transfer functions

Tags: matlab, sum, transfer-function

I'm trying to add two transfer functions together, for example:

```
tf1=tf(1,[1 0]);  
tf2=tf(2,[1 0]);  
tsum=tf1+tf2
```

MATLAB considers tf1 and tf2 as blocks connected in series and therefore multiplies tf1 and tf2 together, the result is:

```
tsum =

3 s
---
s^2

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

how can I get MATLAB to return the sum of tf1 and tf2 ? so the transfer function that i'm looking for is:

```
3
-
s
```

Comment: You are looking for parallel combination, so use `parallel(tf1,tf2)`

Comment: For those of you trying this at home: remember these functions are part of the Control System Toolbox and are not part of basic Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EDU>> minreal(tsum)

ans =

  3
  -
  s

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

see

http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/minreal.html